# Count of one if there are more than one entry in the result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @BranchNum AS INT

SET @StartDate = '2019-10-22'
SET @EndDate = '2019-10-23'
set @BranchNum = '4'

SELECT DISTINCT s.branch AS [Branch], s.CREATEDBYUSER AS [Teller Number],
acct.accountnumber AS [Account Number],
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
                        AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL
                        AND (s.OPENDATE >= @StartDate AND s.OPENDATE <= 
@EndDate)
                   then s.PARENTACCOUNT
                   END
    ) AS [Shares],
CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
         AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL 
    THEN s.balance 
    else 0
END AS [SharesBalance],
CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
         AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL
    THEN s.TYPE
    ELSE 0
END AS [Share Type],
CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null
         AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL
    then s.DESCRIPTION 
    ELSE NULL
    END AS [Share Description],
CASE When c.TYPE in (15,16,17) 
         AND c.STATUS = 1 
         AND c.CLOSEDATE is null 
         AND (c.ISSUEDATE >= @StartDate AND c.ISSUEDATE <= @EndDate)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS [Debit]
from ARCUSYM000.dbo.ACCOUNT acct
INNER join ARCUSYM000.dbo.savings s
    on acct.ACCOUNTNUMBER = s.PARENTACCOUNT
    and s.ProcessDate = acct.ProcessDate
INNER join arcuSYM000.dbo.CARD c 
    on acct.ACCOUNTNUMBER = c.PARENTACCOUNT
    and c.ProcessDate = acct.ProcessDate
where acct.CLOSEDATE is null  
    AND s.CLOSEDATE is null 
    AND s.chargeoffdate is null 
    AND (
        (s.OPENDATE >= @StartDate AND s.OPENDATE <= @EndDate)
        OR (acct.OPENDATE >= @StartDate AND acct.OPENDATE <= @EndDate)
        )
    AND acct.memberstatus = 0 
    AND s.branch is not null 
    AND s.branch = @BranchNum
    AND s.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    AND acct.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 
112)
   AND c.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
GROUP BY s.BRANCH, s.CREATEDBYUSER, acct.ACCOUNTNUMBER, s.CLOSEDATE,
   s.CHARGEOFFDATE, s.BALANCE, s.TYPE, s.DESCRIPTION, c.TYPE,
   c.STATUS, c.USAGEDATE, c.CLOSEDATE, c.ISSUEDATE, acct.STATEMENTMAILCODE,
   s.SHARECODE, s.OVERDRAFTTOLERANCE, s.OPENDATE, s.PARENTACCOUNT
ORDER BY Branch, [Teller Number], [Account Number]
```

Right now I'm getting "1" back for both rows in the Debit column if there are two rows of the same account number. Is there a way for me to get only one "1" if there is more than one entry of the same account number?
I'm not sure if I need to make this whole query a subquery and create a case outside of that to get only one "1" back in the result.

My Current Result:
[image: My current Result:]

My Desired Result:
[image: My desired result]

Comment: You have a couple of issues here. You have a left join but then you have where predicates that turn it into an inner join. Also, you have **AND s.branch IN (@BranchNum)** which implies you might pass in a delimited list of BranchNumbers. That will not work. You would either need dynamic sql, or to pass in a table valued parameter instead. And DISTINCT and a GROUP BY in the same query?

Comment: For the question at hand we need some sample data, table definitions etc...the kinds of things needed to understand the question. [mcve]

Comment: What is your definition of DEBIT?  I don't understand why all of the records with the same account number wouldn't be debit.  How do you decide *which* of the rows should get debit=1?

Comment: @avery_larry, I would like the first of the two same account numbers to have debit=1, and the second of the two same account numbers to have debit = 0.

Comment: Define first. How do you know which one is first and which one is not first?

Comment: I was thinking that I could just find the top or max if there are more than one entry for the account number, then set that to 1, but I'm not sure.